# Platform specific components in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm pretty sure this is straightforward, but I can't quite see how to bring it together.  At the moment my app works perfectly in iOS, but I've used a few controls which are not Android compatible:

```
<View style={containerStyle}>
  <Text style={labelStyle}>Drink:</Text>
  <SegmentedControlIOS
    tintColor={styleBackground}
    style={{ flex: 2 }}
    values={['Value1', 'Value2']}
    selectedIndex={this.state.drink}
    onChange={(event) => {
      this.setState({ drink: event.nativeEvent.selectedSegmentIndex });
    }}
  />
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }} />
</View>
```

I want to use the [React-Native-Segmented-Android](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-segmented-android) library to fix this. I feel like I should be able to do something like:

```
<View style={containerStyle}>
  <Text style={labelStyle}>Drink:</Text>
  const Component = Platform.select({
      ios: () => require('SegmentedControlIOS'),
      android: () => require('react-native-segmented-android'),
  })(      
    tintColor={styleBackground}
    style={{ flex: 2 }}
    values={['Value1', 'Value2']}
    selectedIndex={this.state.drink}
    onChange={(event) => {
      this.setState({ drink: event.nativeEvent.selectedSegmentIndex });
    }}
  />);
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }} />
</View>
```

but that (perhaps unsurprisingly) doesn't work.  Can anyone point me to the correct method?  I know I can just use two different files for iOS/Android but I'd rather keep it together in one if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would create a sepeare component and this component would return segment according to platform but you can create an inner function as an alternative. call this function in render to handle decide which platform app runs and return segment according to platform.

```
_segmentPicker() {
        if (Platform.OS == 'android') {
          return (
              <SegmentedControlIOS
        tintColor={styleBackground}
        style={{ flex: 2 }}
        values={['Value1', 'Value2']}
        selectedIndex={this.state.drink}
        onChange={(event) => {
          this.setState({ drink: event.nativeEvent.selectedSegmentIndex });
        }}
      />
            );
        } else if (Platform.OS == 'ios') {
      return (
           <SegmentedControlIOS
        tintColor={styleBackground}
        style={{ flex: 2 }}
        values={['Value1', 'Value2']}
        selectedIndex={this.state.drink}
        onChange={(event) => {
          this.setState({ drink: event.nativeEvent.selectedSegmentIndex });
        }}
      />
            );
    }
  }


render(){
 return (
  <View>
   {this._segmentPicker()}
   .
   .
  </View>
 );
}
```