# SegmentedControlIOS is not supported on this platform error React Native

Tags: android, react-native, uisegmentedcontrol

So I upgraded my react-native to 0.57.3 and then launch the app in android.
But the previous SegmentedControlIOS is replace with this error message.
Does it mean my android sdk version is too high and I can no longer use this component?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SegmentedControlIOS` in `react-native` is only developed for `iOS platform` by `Facebook`.

So this component will not available for Android.

You can differentiate the platform specific components by `Platform` in `react-native`.

```
import {Platform, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const Component = Platform.select({
  ios: () => require('ComponentIOS'),
  android: () => require('ComponentAndroid'),
})();

<Component />;
```

If you want use `SegmentControl` for both `iOS` and `android` please go for `react-native-segmented-control-tab`

```
npm install react-native-segmented-control-tab --save
```

Please visit https://github.com/kirankalyan5/react-native-segmented-control-tab

**Android**

[image]

**iOS:**

[image]

Comment: I still do not know how to use it, where do I put this code, to a external file or within the component? Say if I have a `SegmentedControlTab` and `SegmentedControlIOS`.  This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534570/platform-specific-components-in-react-native seems good but cannot work

Comment: Actually what I really asked was how to return the right component from the two in the runtime, according to the host platform. I do not know how to use your code to achieve that. If you look at the linked I provided, you will know what I mean. But it is kind of beyond the original question and I think you have got the original question answered.

Comment: I've always stick to the question also my answer be too. I've checked mentioned link and wondered why that guy is returning for android platform 'coz _SegmentControlIOS_ available only for iOS not android. So I thought you are looking for cross-platform component available for both platforms...!!!

Comment: this lib does not have width option which wrap the child size